# How to override the URL that Next.js generates for opengraph-image.tsx?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Next.js provides a way to auto generates open-graph images by providing [`opengraph-image.tsx`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/opengraph-image) file.

As an example, I've added such file to this route:

https://ray.run/blog/organizing-playwright-tests-using-tags

This works as expected locally. However, if you look at the generated HTML code of the page, at the time of writing this, it links to:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="http://localhost:6400/blog/organizing-playwright-tests-using-tags/opengraph-image?e0b86842aed430f7"/>
```

It is not clear which setting of [next.js](/questions/tagged/next.js) is controlling this behaviour.

I tried looking at [`next.config.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js), but none of the settings appear to control this URL.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it is the [`metadataBase`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#metadatabase) setting, and it should be set in `layout.tsx`:

```
import { Metadata } from 'next';
 
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  metadataBase: new URL('https://acme.com/api'),
};
```